# Error message installing Python 1.9.3 with rbenv

Tags: ruby, octopress

```
    BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/nm/7dd74jb52s16cfnjp_st1j8c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130814195519.99873
Results logged to /var/folders/nm/7dd74jb52s16cfnjp_st1j8c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130814195519.99873.log

Last 10 log lines:
x ruby-1.9.3-p0/win32/winmain.c
/var/folders/nm/7dd74jb52s16cfnjp_st1j8c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130814195519.99873/ruby-1.9.3-p0 /var/folders/nm/7dd74jb52s16cfnjp_st1j8c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130814195519.99873 ~
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/nm/7dd74jb52s16cfnjp_st1j8c0000gn/T/ruby-build.20130814195519.99873/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Above is the error message I received when trying to do the install. I am TOTALLY new to ruby and I usually have just followed directions when installing packages, so I don't quite understand how to fix bugs.

If it helps, I was following the directions on this site:
http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/

Comment: Whoa there. Your title says you are trying to install Python using rbenv. Want to explain where that's documented? Don't install things from someone else's say-so, instead follow the official directions from the source site https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you are on but it appears it's OS X.

Do you have XCode with the command-line tools installed? Rbenv is a simple install and has worked on multiple OSes in my experience, but you have to have the compilers and tools installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this:

`checking whether the C compiler works... no`

It looks you have a Mac and the C compiler not installed.

You should download and install from here:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Although I am confused why your title has Python and you are new to Ruby. No offense but it's like you are saying I have a question about English I am new to Spanish.